# Rounded value Tierprice percentage

Tags: magento2, tierprice, percentage

I'm trying to set a decimal value to a percentage discount on a tierprice.

The problem is that when it's saved the value is becoming an int instead of a decimal.

Example
if I set a percentage to 1.23% after save => 1%

[image]

after saving it

[image]

Any way that it keeps the decimal value ?

Thanks

Comment: one quick way of doing it is *100 on save/post and /100 display, but I did it on a very particular situation that I can't remember now ... I'll look further later today

Comment: see example of `number_format()` in use : vendor/magento/module-currency-symbol/Block/Adminhtml/System/Currency/Rate/Matrix.php:112

Comment: @emetik did you found any solution?